# Возвращение на аутентификацию при перезагрузке UI после смены темы приложения при первом запуске приложения

Tags: kotlin, firebase, аутентификация

При первом запуске приложения моего и перехода в настройки(код фрагмента настроек представлен) при смене темы перезагружается UI и выкидывает на авторизацию Firebase,помогите решить проблему, первое мобильное приложение и много чего еще не понятно.

```
package com.example.coursework.screens.settings

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.text.TextUtils
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.example.coursework.MainActivity
import com.example.coursework.databinding.FragmentSettingsBinding
import com.example.coursework.repositories.User.UserInfo
import com.example.coursework.repositories.User.UserRepository
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class Settings : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSettingsBinding

    private val repository = UserRepository()

    private lateinit var currentUser: UserInfo

    private var currentTheme: Int = 0
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        val currentTheme = getSelectedTheme()
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(currentTheme)
        binding.themePreference.text = "App theme now: ${currentTheme}"

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.let {
            binding.pageProgress.isVisible = true
            repository.getCurrentUserById(it, object : UserRepository.FetchSportsmanListener {
                override fun onFetchSportsman(user: UserInfo) {
                    currentUser = user
                    showDetails(currentUser, it)
                }
            })
        }
        val googleSignInClient =
            GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        //Logout function
        binding.logoutButton.setOnClickListener {
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                .setTitle("You have pressed the logout button")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?")
                .setNegativeButton("No, I don't want", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes, I am really sure") { _, _ ->
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                    googleSignInClient.signOut()
                    startActivity(Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java))
                    requireActivity().finish()
                }
                .show()
        }
        // Theme changing
        binding.themePreference.setOnClickListener {
            showThemeDialog()
        }
        // Notifications in settings
        binding.notifications.setOnClickListener {
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                .setTitle("Notifications Disabled")
                .setMessage("Please enable notifications for this app to receive reminders.")
                .setPositiveButton("Enable") { _, _ ->
                    // app settings notifications enabled
                    val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, requireActivity().packageName)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .show()
        }
    }

    private fun showDetails(currentUser: UserInfo, it: FirebaseUser) {
        binding.updateUserName.setText(currentUser.displayName)
        binding.email.text = it.email
        currentUser.photo?.let {
            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                Picasso.get().load(currentUser.photo.toString()).into(binding.userPhoto)
            }
        }

        binding.userPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.type = "image/*"
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            profilePhotoChooser.launch(intent)
        }

        binding.updateUserPhoto.setOnClickListener {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid?.let {
                updateProfilePhoto(it)
            }
        }

        binding.name.setEndIconOnClickListener {
            updateUserName()
        }

        binding.pageProgress.isVisible = false
    }

    private fun updateUserName() {
        binding.pageProgress.isVisible = true
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(binding.updateUserName.text)) {
            binding.updateUserName.error = "Name is empty!"
            return
        }
        val request = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(binding.updateUserName.text.toString())
            .build()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updateProfile(request)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    updateDatabaseUser()
                    binding.pageProgress.isVisible = false
                }
            }
    }

    private fun updateProfilePhoto(userId: String) {
        binding.pageProgress.isVisible = true

        val ref: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
            .child("profile_photos/${userId}")

        profilePhotoUri?.let {
            ref.putFile(it).addOnSuccessListener {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    updateFirebaseUserPhoto(uri)
                    updateDatabaseUser(uri.toString())
                    binding.pageProgress.isVisible = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateDatabaseUser(path: String = currentUser.photo ?: "") {
        val user = UserInfo(
            displayName = binding.updateUserName.text.toString(),
            uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid,
            photo = path
        )
        UserRepository().createOrUpdateUser(user)
    }

    private fun updateFirebaseUserPhoto(uri: Uri) {
        val request = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setPhotoUri(uri)
            .build()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updateProfile(request)
    }

    private var profilePhotoUri: Uri? = null

    private var profilePhotoChooser =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                result.data?.let { imageUri ->
                    binding.userPhoto.setImageURI(imageUri.data)
                    profilePhotoUri = imageUri.data
                }
            }
        }

    private fun showThemeDialog() {
        val themes = arrayOf(
            "Light",
            "Dark",
            "System default"
        )
        val checkedItem = when (binding.themePreference.text.toString()) {
            "Light" -> 0
            "Dark" -> 1
            else -> 2
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle("Select Application Theme")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(themes, checkedItem) { dialog, which ->
                val selectedTheme = when (which) {
                    0 -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
                    1 -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
                    else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
                }
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(selectedTheme)
                currentTheme = selectedTheme
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .show()
    }

    private fun getSelectedTheme(): Int {
        return when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
            else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
        }
    }
}
```

а также хмл код фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ElementTheme"
    tools:context=".screens.settings.Settings">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_border"
            android:hint="@string/display_user_email"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/userPhoto"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_verified_user_24"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/updateUserPhoto"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_save"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userPhoto"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/display_user_name"
            app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_save"
            app:endIconMode="custom"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userPhoto">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/updateUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintTextFieldSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout_button"
            android:layout_width="129dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@string/logout_button"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userPhoto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pageProgress"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:theme="@style/ElementTheme"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/themePreference"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_border"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/notifications"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_border"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_notifications"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/themePreference" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```